# Autowiring in mybatis-spring 1.2.0

Tags: spring, mybatis

Javadoc to `SqlSessionDaoSupport` class says:

> ...@Autowired was removed from setSqlSessionTemplate and
>   setSqlSessionFactory  in version 1.2.0.

**Why?**  In this case I have to manualy set sqlSessionFactory to my daos and also to test classes(I use dbUnit for persistance tests)

Comment: try to inject it from xml context file

Comment: I have more than 50 daos that extends this class and daos are declared using component-scan. Do you propose mannualy declare 50 daos in xml?

Comment: also I have many test classes that also extend this class(maybe not directly). Do I have also to declare test classes in xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Autowired` was removed according to this issue : https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=763

As a generic purpose framework, MyBatis should not make strong assertions such as "There's only one sqlSessionFactory in the ApplicationContext", that's why `@Autowired` was removed.

As a workaround, you could write your own `MyAppSqlSessionDaoSupport` that extends `SqlSessionDaoSupport`, and override `setSqlSessionFactory(...)` with

```
@Autowired
public void setSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
  if (!this.externalSqlSession) {
    this.sqlSession = new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
  }
}
```

Then, make your DAOs extends `MyAppSqlSessionDaoSupport` instead of `SqlSessionDaoSupport`.

Comment: It's obviouse for me that I should write a class that overrides that method and extend all my classes from that class, but the question was in a purpose of removing that annotation. Ok, there are some problems with Autowiring sqlSessionFactory and template, why not to remove only one annotation?

Comment: It wasn't obvious that you knew it when looking at your question and yours comments. Still, what is unclear with the fact that `@Autowired` makes assertion that only one bean of a specific type exists in the application context, whereas there can be several ? One application can have several SqlSessionFactory and another one can have several SqlSessionTemplate.

Comment: as far as I know, spring will throw an exception at startup when more than one bean pretend to be autowired

Comment: how about MapperFactoryBean which also extends SqlSessionDaosupport? If one wants mappers to be scanned during startup, MapperFactoryBean that will be created will not have reference to SqlSessionFactory unless somehow to set it

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see what is still unclear to you. Again, `@Autowired` annotation must be used only if you are sure that there will have exactly one matching bean. I'm currently working on an application with 3 distinct database, and so 3 `SqlSessionFactory`. Thus `@Autowired` can't work for me since, there would be 3 beans available for the required type. So I must use Spring XML configuration for each `MapperScannerConfigurer` to point to the wanted `SqlSessionFactory`.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, in version 1.2.0 of mybatis-spring there is a namespace <mybatis:scan/> which uses `MapperScannerBeanDefinitionParser`(which internally use the same mechanism as `MapperScannerConfigurer`). In this version `MapperFactoryBean` doesn't have @Autowired annotation, but somehow sqlSessionfactory is auwtowired into it. I only specify basePackage on <mybatis:scan/>. i don't understand how does it autowires sqlSessionFactory into MapperFactoryBean in this version

Comment: made a little investigation. `<mybatis:scan/>` element in 1.2.0 version behave the same as with @Autowired annotation, so If one uses it and have more than 1 sqlSessionfactory - problems will occur(`ClassPathMapperScanner` sets AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE mode on `BeanDefinition` of `MapperfactoryBean`)

Comment: Great analysis and good to know for `<mybatis:scan/>`. As usual, Spring namespace are useful for simple cases, but when more control is needed, better off using plain old XML config.